# How do I make a window (already running task) visible using pywinauto?

Tags: python, pywinauto

Besides looking for answers on this site, I checked out

[pywinauto.application module](https://pywinauto.github.io/docs/code/pywinauto.application.html#module-pywinauto.application)

and

[Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

but I'm still stumped.

I manually start notepad and want the first while block of the following code to make the notepad window visible. The second while block works but I am confused about the line

```
dlg_spec = app.UntitledNotepad
```

What is going on here? What kind of a python method is this?

Question: How do I get the first while block of code make the window titled

```
Untitled - Notepad
```

visible?

```
#--------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*
# Desc: Set focus on a window
# #--------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*

import sys
import pywinauto


#                                  # Manually started Notepad
#                                  # Want to make it visible (windows focus)
#                                  # Program runs, but...
while 1:
    handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title='Untitled - Notepad')[0] 
    app = pywinauto.application.Application()
    ac = app.connect(handle=handle)
    print(ac)
    topWin = ac.top_window_()
    print(topWin)
    sys.exit()

#                                  # Working Sample Code
while 0:
    app = pywinauto.Application().start('notepad.exe')
    # describe the window inside Notepad.exe process
#                                  # ?1: '.UntitledNotepad' - huh?
    dlg_spec = app.UntitledNotepad
    # wait till the window is really open
    actionable_dlg = dlg_spec.wait('visible')
    sys.exit()
```

---

For convenience this code does the trick:

```
#                                  # Manually started Notepad
#                                  # Want to make it visible (windows focus).
#                                  # 
#                                  # Two or three lines solution provided by
#                                  # Vasily Ryabov's overflow answer
#                                  # (wrapper ribbon and bow stuff).
while 1:
    app = pywinauto.application.Application().connect(title="Untitled - Notepad")
    dlg_spec = app.window(best_match="UntitledNotepad")
    dlg_spec.set_focus()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: It would be better to use `win32gui` here if you are on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first while loop should be re-written using the same methods except `find_windows` (it's low level and not recommended for direct usage). You need method `.set_focus()` to bring the window to foreground.

```
app = pywinauto.Application().connect(title="Untitled - Notepad")
app.UntitledNotepad.set_focus()
```

Creating window specification `dlg_spec = app.UntitledNotepad` means that `app` method `__getattribute__` is called. Finally this line is equivalent to `dlg_spec = app.window(best_match="UntitledNotepad")`. To find the actual wrapper you need to call `.wait(...)` or `.wrapper_object()`.

But when you call an action (like `.set_focus()`), Python can do the `wrapper_object()` call for you implicitly (while accessing attribute `set_focus` dynamically).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you using the `win32gui` library for this task as shown below:

```
import win32gui

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Notepad')

win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd, 9)
```

The number `9` represents `SW_RESTORE` as shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Works with `hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Untitled - Notepad')`. Can win32gui handle anything that pywinauto does?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by that question, but win32gui is mostly for managing windows on the desktop platforms.

Comment: pywinauto is a kind of wrapper around win32gui/win32api, but can work with MS UI Automation API also (COM library UIAutomationClient.dll), this is also for desktop platforms.

Comment: Also pywinauto hides many details of Win32 API. Of course, the core concept requires some short learning, but further you don't need to read all the details about every window message, its params, structure fields and so on. And for UIAutomationClient.dll backend the core concept works the same way.